# String with [[ to array

Tags: java, arrays, api

I have the following String, that returns from API

[
[
1680373800000,
"1.27860000",
"1.28210000",
],
[
1680374700000,
"1.27610000",
"1.28000000",
"0"
]
]

How to convert this to Java Arrays?
Thanks a lot :)

I tried differents solutions but I can not reach the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a JSON String, you can use the Gson library to achieve this.

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import java.util.Arrays;

Gson gson = new Gson();
Object[][] data = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Object[][].class);

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(data));
```

The output should be:

```
[[1.6803738E12, 1.2786, 1.2821], [1.6803747E12, 1.2761, 1.28, 0.0]]
```